# Conditioning pandas Dataframe on an Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to condition on an array I've created.

```
first6 = df["Tbl_Name_Dur"].unique()[0:6]
for element in first6:
    print(element)

df_test = df[df['Tbl_Name_Dur'] for element in first6]
```

I've printed the elements and that works. How do I condition on selecting my dataframe based on first6. I've tried the following:

```
df_test = df[df['Tbl_Name_Dur'] in first6]
df_test = df[df['Tbl_Name_Dur'] == first6]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
  
data_dict = {'col': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,8 ])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
first6 = df.col.unique()[0:6]

df = df[df.isin(first6)]
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Alternatively**, you can use a `lambda` function together with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import pandas as pd
  
data_dict = {'col': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 ])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
first6 = df.col.unique()[0:6]
df = df[df.col.map(lambda x : x in first6)]
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
   col
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  4
5  5
6  6
```